# How to echo a string with non-alpha numeric characters into a file in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to do something similar in a real pipeline, so I first run the following in Jenkins script console. The string is a modified Git commit message that I get with the `git log` command.

```
String s = "JIRA-12334 | Prevent inserting "&#x27" in place of apostrophes in patient's names when exporting to CSV."

sh """
  echo \"$s\" > someFile
"""
```

and get the following error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected char: ''' @ line 1, column 126.
   s names when exporting to CSV.'
                                 ^
```

Trying

```
sh """
   echo "$s" > someFile
"""
```

gives the following error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected char: '#' @ line 1, column 55.
   Patient statement inserting "&#x27" in p
                                 ^
```

What's the trick to make this work?

Comment: Try `echo "$s" > someFile`

Comment: @tim_yates, thanks I tried that. I updated my post.

Comment: Ahhh, so double quotes in bash are special and it tries to do things. Try single quotes `echo '$s' > someFile`

Comment: And pray that the message never contains a single quote 